# Facebook Marketing API, currency

Tags: facebook, iso, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-feed

In Facebook Marketing API i using DKK currency.

By documentation, this currency is from ISO-4217 list.

But i still get error: "please use the standard ISO 4217 currency code", why?

Price line:

```
<g:price><![CDATA[ 90 DKK ]]></g:price>
```

Answer (score 0):

DKK is a supported currency in Marketing API for all ad accounts. See full list here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies. You can post this issue on Facebook Marketing Developer Community: https://www.facebook.com/groups/pmdcommunity/